# Setting TimeOut in CURL using PHP

Tags: php, http, curl, timeout

I've searched a lot about setting time out for curl request in PHP, but none seems to be helpful.
I'm using CURL-7.15.5 version. I'm trying to set time-out for a request in milliseconds. I know that in curl-7.16.* there is new option CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, which can set time out in milliseconds. Is there any way to user CURLOPT_TIMEOUT (7.15.5 style) to setup time-out less than a minute?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Edit: Is it possible to set timeout in milliseconds in curl 7.15.5 version?

Answer (score 0):

Check this links

[**CURLOPT_TIMEOUT -**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) defines the amount of time that any cURL function is allowed to take to execute.

**[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT -](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)** defines the maximum amount of time to wait for the connection to complete

Comment: whats the minimum can I set with CURLOPT_TIMEOUT? Is it one second? Can I set millisecond using this?

Comment: You didnt accepted my answer bro...Please accept if it helped you...By the way CURLOPT_TIMEOUT -> The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

Comment: my question was to know if I can use milliseconds rather seconds in CURLOPT_TIMEOUT. I knew those options already.